# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo'

Tags: c#

I have library and console program. The program dynamically load library. In library exist byte array. I try get this array. In program:

```
MemberInfo[] ByteArrayFile = HtmlPackage.GetMember("HtmlFile");
FieldInfo field;
try
{
   field = (FieldInfo)ByteArrayFile[0];//throw exception here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  String err = e.ToString();
  throw e;
}
byte[] HtmlFileArray = (byte[])field.GetValue(htmlPackage);
```

This error throw exception:

> "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo'.\r\n   at ...

So how it's fixed?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Cast to `PropertyInfo` or `MemberInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields (`FieldInfo`) and properties (`PropertyInfo`) do not share an API - so you need to work around it:

```
MemberInfo member = ByteArrayFile[0];
byte[] HtmlFileArray;
switch (member.MemberType)
{
    case MemberTypes.Field:
        HtmlFileArray = (byte[])(((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(htmlPackage));
        break;
    case MemberTypes.Property:
        HtmlFileArray = (byte[])(((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(htmlPackage));
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException(member.MemberType.ToString());
}
```

However, this is **much** easier (and more efficient too (due to strategy caching), without introducing any additional weaknesses):

```
byte[] HtmlFileArray = ((dynamic)htmlPackage).HtmlFile;
```